# how can the voter verify that the candidate’s choice has not changed?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

When the electoral process is over, how can the voter verify that the candidate’s choice has not changed?
I want to add a function in the contractual contract, but I don't know how to construct this function
I want an example when the voter puts his address, the system returns the name of the candidate who has been chosen since the election process.
i need a function in smart contract  to do this please

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
contract Voting {
    // Model a Candidate
     struct Candidate {
        uint256 id;
        string name;
        uint256 voteCount;
    }
    mapping(address => bool) public voters;
    mapping(uint256 => Candidate) public candidates;
    // Store Candidates count
    uint256 public candidatesCount;
    // voted event
    event votedEvent(uint256 indexed _candidateId);

    constructor() public {
        addCandidate("Candidate #1");
        addCandidate("Candidate #2");
        addCandidate("Candidate #3");
    }

    function addCandidate(string memory _name) private {
        candidatesCount++;
        candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _name, 0);
    }

    function vote(uint256 _candidateId) public {
        // require that they haven't voted before
        require(!voters[msg.sender]);

        // require a valid candidate
        require(_candidateId > 0 && _candidateId <= candidatesCount);

        // record that voter has voted
        voters[msg.sender] = true;

        // update candidate vote Count
        candidates[_candidateId].voteCount++;

        // trigger voted event
        emit votedEvent(_candidateId);
    }
    function getCondidateName(address adr)  pure  public returns( string memory ){
        // here i need to create thecode of the verify }}
```

Comment: The Candidate struct doesn't have an address type variable. What is the "adr" argument in getCondidateName()?

Comment: i know this wrong could you correct this please